# Getting Error while using Division in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm getting error when I use this formula in SSRS 2017:

> Operator '/' is not defined for types 'integer' and 'System.TimeSpan'
>
> Operator '*' is not defined for types 'System.TimeSpan'  and 'System.TimeSpan'

```
=IIF(
     100 / (DateAdd("d", -(Day(Today)), Today) - 
            DateSerial(Year(DateAdd("m", -1, Now())),  1, 1)
            )
     * ((Today - DateSerial(Year(DateAdd("m", -1, Now())),  1, 1)) / 100) > 1, 
     1, 
     100 / (DateAdd("d",-(Day(Today)), Today) - 
            DateSerial(Year(DateAdd("m", -1, Now())),  1, 1)
            )
     * ((Today - DateSerial(Year(DateAdd("m", -1, Now())),  1, 1)) / 100)
     )
```

Comment: Anyone ..... please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DateDiff()` instead of `-`:

```
=IIF(
 100 / DateDiff("d", DateAdd("d", -Day(Today), Today),
                DateSerial(Year(DateAdd("m", -1, Now())),  1, 1)
                )
 * (DateDiff("d", Today, DateSerial(Year(DateAdd("m", -1, Now())),  1, 1)) / 100) > 1, 
 1, 
 100 / DateDiff("d", DateAdd("d",-(Day(Today)), Today), 
                DateSerial(Year(DateAdd("m", -1, Now())),  1, 1)
                )
 * DateDiff("d", Today, DateSerial(Year(DateAdd("m", -1, Now())),  1, 1)) / 100
 )
```

Comment: Still Getting error .. "Overload resolution faild because no accessible 'Datediff' accepts this number of arguments/

Comment: Yes, I forgot the first argument in `DateDiff()`. A quick google search based on the error message would have lead you to the right track, that a argument in the function is missing. I updated my answer.